# Reference value from row depending on value in another cell

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, filter, vlookup

I am looking to copy a cell value based on the correct value of another cell in that row.

Example:
On a Sheet 2 I have a dropdown with all values from column A1. I select the value Banana, I now want to also bring over the value Yellow from column B1 to be added to column B2.

Sheet 1:

| Column A1 | Column B1 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Red |
| Banana | Yellow |

Sheet 2:

| Column A2 | Column B2 |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | ? |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2; Sheet1!A:B; 2; 0)
```